# Python logging module not logging info even after level is set

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to do some basic logging. I'm doing the following:

```
log = logging.getLogger('test')

log.error('test') # 'test' gets logged

log.info('test') # Nothing gets logged, as expected

log.setLevel(logging.INFO) # Now info should be logged, right?

log.info('test') # No output

log.setLevel(logging.INFO) # Getting desperate

log.info('test') # Still nothing
```

What aspect of the logging module am I missing?

Comment: Too bad none of the answers elaborate further on why this is so (further than "you need to add handlers"). That is really worth explaining since this behaviour is truly counter intuitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have forgot to add handlers i.e. `logging.basicConfig()`, can you check if following code works for you.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger('test')
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.error('test')
log.info('test')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure logging before you use it like below. You can configure it beautifully in python.

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(name)25s %(lineno)4d %(levelname)8s: %(message)s', level=40)
```

above statement will print timestamp, name of the file, line number, level type, message

level of logging also can be set during basic Config itself (40 = ERROR)

Comment: Minor note, 40 is not DEBUG, 10 is. 40 is ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to call `basicConfig`.

However, the issue is about handlers (as pointed out by @Mahesh Karia).

You see, if you don't define some handlers you are dependent on whatever is already "in place" for you and that raises lots of confusion.

Check this:

You create your "test" logger

```
>>> log = logging.getLogger('test')
```

which prints WARNING messages but does not print INFO messages even after setting the level to INFO:

```
>>> log.warning('hi')
hi
>>> log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> log.info('hi')
>>>
```

(personally, I think this is very wrong behaviour)

It can be "solved" by manipulating "handlers".

Your "test" logger has none

```
>>> log.handlers
[]
```

nor does it parent, the "root logger"

```
>>> log.parent
<RootLogger root (WARNING)>
>>> log.parent.handlers
[]
```

however, one can add a handler easy enough (to the root logger)

```
>>> log.parent.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

and now your "test" logger "works":

```
>>> log.info('hi')
hi
```

PS. Was using Python 3.8.2 prompt after importing `logging` module.